# Call add_action() in function wordpress

Tags: actions, save-post

I have a problem with a WordPress hook. I want to call an action in another actions callback, but it doesn't seem to work. I want to call `add_meta_tag` action only if the page is saved. This is what I have:

```
function saveCustomField($post_id)
{
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_meta_tag' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'saveCustomField' );

function add_meta_tag(){
    echo "TEST";
}
```

How can I get the above to work properly?

Comment: `save_post` is called only in the admin pages and not on public side then `saveCustomField` is never called with this code. what do you want to display on public side ?

Comment: Other than the comment above, it's not recommended to do this. There is a chance that you get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @mmm and @JackJohansson: I respectfully disagree with both of you, that  `save_post` is fired only on admin side. That's a myth! @JackJohansson: there is no chance of getting stuck in an infinite loop, if done correctly, by removing your action within the callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking about this entirely wrong. A meta tag isn't something you add when a post gets saved, it's something that gets added to the output when a post is *viewed*.

So instead of trying to hook the action inside `save_post`, you hook it on every page load, and *inside* the hook you check if your custom field exists on the post being viewed. If it is, you output the tag.

```
function wpse_283352_add_meta_tag() {
    if ( is_singular() {
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_custom_field', true );

        if ( $meta ) {
            echo '<meta name="my_custom_field" content="' . esc_attr( $meta ) . '">';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_283352_add_meta_tag' );
```

That function just goes in your plugin file/functions file, not inside any other hook.

Answer (score 0):

The `save_post` hook is fired after the data is saved to the database - whenever post or page is created or updated - only on admin pages.

The `wp_head` hook fires when `wp_head()` function is run and this do not happen on admin pages.

This won't work. Where and when you want to add the meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you can't.

The code is fine, but there is a flaw in logic. `wp_head` action is set too late. Headers are already sent, therefore `wp_head` will never fire! This code below, will prove two points. First: `save_post` will fire on both, admin pages, and on front end, as well. Second: it's easy to prevent an infinite loop in callback function.

In `functions.php`:

```
function saveCustomField($post_id) {

    // to prevent an infinite loop
    remove_action('save_post', 'saveCustomField', 10);

    // to prove that function was called
    error_log('I am here to add action');

    add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tag');
}
add_action('save_post', 'saveCustomField');

function add_meta_tag(){
    error_log('TEST');
    //echo "TEST";
}
```

In my page template ( front end ):

```
wp_update_post(array('ID' => 79, 'post_title' => 'My Current Test',));
```

In error_log:

```
[19-Oct-2017 02:57:08 UTC] I am here to add action
```

My post's title had been updated, `save_post` was fired, and `wp_head` wasn't.

Comment: Sorry, new on wordpress. How can I make to use save_post on a post?

Answer (score 0):

I want to add the meta tag when publish/update button is fired. I have a checkbox on the admin page that add/remove meta tag. For info, it's intended for a plugin.

```
function saveCustomField($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
}

if (
    !isset($_POST['my_custom_nonce']) ||
    !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['my_custom_nonce'], 'my_custom_nonce_'.$post_id)
) {
    return;
}

if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
    return;
}

if (isset($_POST['_my_custom_field'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_my_custom_field', $_POST['_my_custom_field']);
    // here
    // >>>>> add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tag');
} else {
    delete_post_meta($post_id, '_my_custom_field');
}
```

}

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'saveCustomField' );

function add_meta_tag(){
    echo "TEST";
}
```

Comment: your `wp_head` will not fire. Headers already sent.